# Documenting networking infrastructure

Tags: networking

I'm looking for Open source web interface for documenting the active and passive parts of a networking infrastructure, cabling.

Answer (score 2):

I think Dia would help you. http://www.osalt.com/dia
Good luck!

Comment: I suspect that, unlike so many other graphics editors/drawing tools (OpenOffice Draw, etc...), Dia is your best bet. But I wouldn't be surprised if there's network templates for others, like Inkscape.

Comment: Thanks for bringing OSALT.com to my attention, it makes for a nice alternative to alternativeto.net :-)

Answer (score 1):

[Gliffy](http://www.gliffy.com/) and [Creately](http://creately.com/Online-Network-Diagram-Software) are online tools for making network topology drawings. 
They are free to use, although perhaps limited in features.
However, I'm not either of these fit your open source requirement.

Google now also has [Drawings](http://www.google.com/google-d-s/drawings/) as part of their Google docs offering, which is meant to compete with Microsoft's Visio.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [Lucid Chart](https://www.lucidchart.com/)? They have some great [network diagrams examples](https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/examples/network_diagram_software).

Comment: I don't think that's an open source product.

Comment: This is not open source and does not address the question.